# How was the Anglo-Norman spelling of 'demesne' 'merely graphic'?

Tags: etymology, french, old-french

> [[OED:]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/49656?redirectedFrom=demesne#eid) The Anglo-Norman spelling ***demesne*** of the law-books, and 17th cent. legal antiquaries, was partly merely graphic (the quiescence of original ***s*** before a consonant leading to the insertion of a non-etymological ***s*** to indicate a long vowel), as in
>   *mesne* = Old French *meien , meen , mean* , modern French *moyen* ;
>    partly perhaps influenced by association with *mesne* itself, in ‘mesne lord’,
>   or with *mesnie* < *mansionāta* house, household establishment.

Seeing only one ***s*** in ***demesne***, I am confused by the OED:
Where is the original ***s***? Where is the non-etymological (so epenthetic) ***s***? [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=demesne&searchmode=none) states less.

Comment: The original s  the OED talks about is in other words than demesne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word comes from Old French *demeine*, and there never was an *s* (so, the original *s* was in their heads). The word is first attested in "English" (French-English legal code-switching) without <s>, and with various spellings. The non-etymological *s* is the only *s* in the word *demesne*.

There are a number of words in French that used to have *s*, which was deleted, and it appears that orthographic <s> was added in these words to indicate that the vowel is long (and, I suppose, that the word is French).